# Replace plus(+) OR space(" ") from url parameter in varnish and redirect them

Tags: regex, redirect, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to replace plus/space with `-` from query params in varnish and redirect them.
**EX.** If url is http://example.com/xyx.html?q=bar+car+Bar
it should redirect to http://example.com/xyx.html?q=bar-car-Bar

**Reason:** OLD page urls are still visible in search engine results.

Here is my **current implementation** in vcl file:
**In vcl_recv:**

```
if (req.url ~ "\?q=" && req.url ~ "\+") {
    set req.http.X-Redirect-URL = "http://" + req.http.host + regsuball(req.url, "([+ ])", "-");
    error 301 req.http.X-Redirect-URL;
}
```

**In vcl_error:**

```
if (obj.status == 301) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 301;
    set obj.response = "Moved Permanently";
    set obj.http.Expires = "Mon, 21 Jul 1980 05:00:00 GMT";
    return (deliver);
}
```

Now its working fine but also replacing all `+` signs from current url.
i.e. http://example.com/xyz+zyx.html?q=bar+car+Bar
is redirecting to http://example.com/xyz-zyx.html?q=bar+car+Bar

Is there any way we could only replace `+` from url parameters and not complete url ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some rudimentary URL parsing to best accomplish this. Try this out:

```
set req.http.X-Redirect-Base = regsuball(req.url, "([^?]+)\??.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Redirect-Query = regsuball(req.url, "[^?]+(\??.*)", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Redirect-Query ~ "\+") {
    set req.http.X-Redirect-URL = "http://" + req.http.host + req.http.X-Redirect-Base + regsuball(req.http.X-Redirect-Query, "([+ ])", "-");
    error 301 req.http.X-Redirect-URL;
}
```

It passes the following Varnish test:

```
varnishtest "Testing converting query string plus and space into hyphen"

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp -body "hello world"
} -repeat 2 -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    include "${pwd}/28215460.vcl";
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -url "/xyz+zyx.html?q=bar+car+Bar" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 301
    expect resp.http.Location == "http://example.com/xyz+zyx.html?q=bar-car-Bar"
} -run

client c2 {
    txreq -url "/xyz+zyx.html?q=bar-car-Bar" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.body == "hello world"
} -run

client c3 {
    txreq -url "/xyz+zyx.html" -hdr "Host: example.com"
    rxresp

    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.body == "hello world"
} -run

varnish v1 -expect client_req == 3
```